Duplicating a record with an auto-increment key
I'm migrating a database from MySQL to SQL Server. In MySQL I have this bit of stored procedure:
Declare cidx int;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS coretmp1;

Create temporary table coretmp1 SELECT * FROM corebuild order by Idx desc limit 1;
select Idx+1 from coretmp1 into cidx;
UPDATE coretmp1 SET Idx = cidx, Piece=0;
INSERT INTO corebuild SELECT * FROM coretmp1;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS coretmp1;

Select cidx;

This way all columns get copied, even if the table is altered, and a new sequential key is generated, which is returned by the script. How can I do this in SQL Server as it does not have Temporary tables and I can't seem to create a table variable from an existing table?

When asking a question you need to just specify your requirements and show your attempt. The fact that you are translating from another system is not relevant. You also need to research the options available in the system you want the solution in. SQL Server definitely has temp tables.

Consider the select * into table2 from table1 syntax

"How can I do this in SQL Server as it does not have Temporary tables" - Yes it does...

IF I read this right you don't need the temp variable since you have a temp table.  I will use a table variable rather than a temp table here and then you don't have to drop it as that happens when it goes out of scope.
Sorry I don't buy into the SELECT * here as I consider that a less than desirable practice; I won't list all the reasons but you can search for reasons why.
IF your Idx is declared as an IDENTITY column you don't need to do this, just insert and it will get the next value ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver16
DECLARE @coretmp AS TABLE (
    (put all actual columns here)
    Piece BIGINT,
    Idx INT
)

INSERT INTO @coretmp (
    (put all actual columns here)
    Piece,
    Idx
)
SELECT TOP(1)
    (put all actual columns here)
    0 AS Piece,
    Idx + 1
FROM corebuild
ORDER BY Idx DESC;

INSERT INTO corebuild (
    (put all actual columns here)
    Piece,
    Idx
)
SELECT
    (put all actual columns here)
    Piece,
    Idx
FROM @coretmp;

/* return the updated value */
SELECT
    Idx
FROM @coretmp;

Now if you do not even NEED to use the return value, you can just insert an updated value of the last read value
INSERT INTO corebuild (
    (put all actual columns here)
    Piece,
    Idx
)
SELECT TOP(1)
    (put all actual columns here)
    0 AS Piece,
    Idx + 1
FROM corebuild
ORDER BY Idx DESC;


" I don't buy into the SELECT * here as I consider that a less than desirable practice" - mostly true until you come across a table with 200 columns and your best practice code turns unreadable/unmaintainable mess.
